# Why can't I link IMG elements to urls like "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Batman_Lee.png"

Tags: javascript

I'm using google custom search to get image results. This is my first test and when I searched for Batman I got this URL found in Wikipedia: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Batman_Lee.png"

When I tried to use it an image element:

```
<img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Batman_Lee.png">
```

I got a blank element. Why is this? Is wikipedia actively preventing people from linking to their images or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the URL you are using is a file/page of wikipedia having image.

The absolute image URL is:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a7/Batman_Lee.png
```

When you link the above URL within an `<img>` tag then it will work.

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a7/Batman_Lee.png">
```

**Note:** You can get the above URL by clicking right mouse button on `image` and copy the `URL`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/owinug/1/edit)

Comment: Consider that Wikipedia also has scaled versions of images; for [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Turbinella_pyrum_01.jpg), there is [the full-size version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Turbinella_pyrum_01.jpg), [a tiny version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Turbinella_pyrum_01.jpg/50px-Turbinella_pyrum_01.jpg), and all sizes in-between.

Comment: thanks, I just realized. I was sure the script was returning image links as I choose .jpg in file type, I suppose the real question would be how do I get the image link using Google Search API